# opencv: single pixal assignment confusion

Tags: c++, opencv

I am recently working with OpenCV and C++ for a project and I found a weird thing:
when I try to access single pixal value in IplImage and assign other value, it could run properly but the result is that it can only operate part of the whole image.

relevant code:

```
IplImage* output_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* current_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
while((current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray)) != 0 )
{
  for (int row=0;row<height;row++)
  {

        uchar* ptr_current_frame = (uchar *)(current_frame->imageData+current_frame->widthStep*row);
        uchar* ptr_output_frame = (uchar *)(output_frame->imageData+output_frame->widthStep*row);
        for (int cols=0;cols<width;cols++)
        {
            //other codes...
            ptr_output_frame[cols]=ptr_current_frame[cols];
        }
  }
}
```

The result is the left part of the image was copied to the output_frame. And when I run the following code:

```
IplImage* output_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* current_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
while((current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray)) != 0 )
{
  for (int row=0;row<height;row++)
  {

        uchar* ptr_current_frame = (uchar *)current_frame->imageData+current_frame->width*row;
        uchar* ptr_output_frame = (uchar *)output_frame->imageData+output_frame->width*row;
        for (int cols=0;cols<width;cols++)
        {
            //other codes...
            ptr_output_frame[cols]=ptr_current_frame[cols];
        }
  }
}
```

I got the upside part of the image in the output_frame.

I cannot get the the whole image copy in output_frame either way. Could anybody help me with this? Thanks a lot!

[updates] 05/16/2015

I have found out that output_frame->widthStep is different from current->widthStep after current_frame is executed in the following code:

```
 current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray);
```

It makes sense why the first part of the code wouldnt work. But I still dont know why the second part of the code doesnt work.
I now have my whole codes updated here and hope you can help me make this right. I am really appreciate your help.

```
CvCapture* video_gray = cvCreateFileCapture("test_gray.avi");
const double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(video_gray, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); 
const int width = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(video_gray, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
const int height = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(video_gray, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
const CvSize size = cvSize(width, height);
IplImage* current_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* output_frame=cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
int flag = 0;
cvNamedWindow("test",1);
cvNamedWindow("test2",1);
while((current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray)) != 0 )
{
    cout<<flag++<<endl;
    if(flag<500) continue;
    for (int row=0;row<height;row++)
    {
        uchar* ptr_current_frame = (uchar *)(current_frame->imageData+current_frame->widthStep*row);
        uchar* ptr_output_frame = (uchar *)(output_frame->imageData+output_frame->widthStep*row);
        for (int cols=0;cols<width;cols++)
        {
            ptr_output_frame[cols]= ptr_current_frame[cols];
        }
    }
    cvShowImage("test",output_frame);
    cvShowImage("test2",current_frame);
    cvWaitKey(10);
}
```

Comment: if you use C++ then please don't use IplImage but cv::Mat image.

Comment: how is `size` initialized? What is `height` and and what value is `current_frame->width` and `current_frame->height` in each iteration?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I have tried to transfer the IplImage to Mat and use current_frame_mat.at<uchar> (row, cols) to assign the value. But the result remains the same and I cannot get the whole image copied. As for size, I initialed it like this:    CvCapture* video_gray = cvCreateFileCapture("test_gray.avi");const int width = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(video_gray, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
 const int height = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(video_gray, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);const CvSize size = cvSize(width, height);    The current_frame->width and current_frame->height do not change in each iteration.

Comment: did you verify that they dont change in each iteration? the getProptery isnt always correct. and you should omit IplImage right in the beginning. use cv::VideoCapture instead.

Comment: Thanks again! I have carefully verified that current_frame->width and current_frame->height dont change in each iteration. They are exactly the same as the way it should be. Also, output_frame->width and output_frame->height is right. However, I find something weird: in my case, current_frame->widthStep=1920, output_frame->widthStep=640. I find that after initialize the IplImage:IplImage* current_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);  the widthStep is 640 and after executing current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray), it became 1920.

Comment: I have also tried to code this part using VideoCapture and I met some problems in open the files. And I couldnt get it run. Is there any way I can fix this problem in IplImage? Thanks!

Comment: can you try to save the iplImges to files directly after capturing and tell whether they are how you expected them to be? use cvSaveImage

Comment: probably you capture BGR images but handle them as 8 bit... I`ll write an answer soon

Comment: added another sample of how to use cv::Mat

Comment: not sure, but maybe you have memory leaks when doing: `IplImage* current_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);` followed by `current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray)` but I'm really not sure there... too long ago that I used IplImages =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't handle the number of channels...

please try

```
IplImage* output_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage* current_frame = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
while((current_frame = cvQueryFrame(video_gray)) != 0 )
{
  for (int row=0;row<height;row++)
  {

    uchar* ptr_current_frame = (uchar *)(current_frame->imageData+current_frame->widthStep*row);
    uchar* ptr_output_frame = (uchar *)(output_frame->imageData+output_frame->widthStep*row);
    for (int cols=0;cols<width;cols++)
    {
        //other codes...
        // here insead take care of the channels too. Only write ne channel to the output
        ptr_output_frame[cols]=ptr_current_frame[cols*current_frame->nChannels];
    }
  }
}
```

but you should really try to switch to C++ API: try something like this:

```
cv::VideoCapture video = cv::VideoCapture("test_gray.avi");

int width = ...
int height = ...

cv::Mat image_captured;
cv::Mat image_gray; // if wanted
cv::Mat image_output1 = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat image_output2 = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC1);

while(video.read(image_captured))
{
    // if you want to convert the image to 
    if(image_captured.channels() > 1)
    {
        cv::cvtColor(image_captured, image_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        image_gray = image_captured;
    }

    [...]
    for(int j=0; j<height; ++j)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<width; ++i)
        {
            image_output1.at<uchar>(j,i) = image_gray.at<uchar>(j,i); // read from single channel image
            image_output1.at<uchar>(j,i) = image_captured.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]; // only read the first channel of a multi-channel image
        }
    }        

}

    cv::imshow("output1", image_output1);
    cv::imshow("output2", image_output2);
    cv::imshow("input", image_capured);

    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

much easier to use, and you can still make it more efficient by using row-pointers in each iteration etc

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Actually I still do not the reason. The video I read in the program is indeed in gray, although it is converted to gray video by my codes. I am a rookie in Opencv and I am very lucky to have you help me with this. Thanks again!

Comment: gray doesn't need to be single channeled... the 3 channel gray color [122,122,122] can be described as a single channel [122] value, but needn't be... typically input images provided by OpenCV are always 3 channel images, if you don't/can't tell something different. e.g. cv::imread has a flag to either always load as grayscale (maybe with conversion) or to load the image the way it is in the original file. If you don't set the flags, it will always be 3 channel images, even if they show gray colors. Maybe cv::VideoCapture (and C equivalent) have different flags/properties, I'm not sure there.

Comment: Get it. Learned a lot from you. Would it be possible for you to recommend some books to learn opencv? I may still use it a lot during my Phd study. Right now I am using Learning Opencv and I think it is kind of too old. LOL.

Comment: it should be able to easily convert each IplImage code version to cv::Mat version. Typically you just change function syntax from cvBLABLA to cv::BLABLA and have a look at OpenCV documentation how to choose parameters. Unfortunately I don't know any good books (although they might exist), but internet is full of nice tutorials, code samples and stackOverflow questions =)

Comment: Honestly, it is my first time to use stackoverflow. It is great. And it is very nice to meet you!